# How can one switch to ttyX in virtualbox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, console

I run VirtualBox in Linux , running CentOS in it , and I can't switch to ttyX in the CentOS since I'll go to the ttyX in my Linux.

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the default Virtualbox configuration, you can use <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, where `RCtrl` is the right control key.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you can send arbitrary keyboard sequences with VirtualBox, but you could try `chvt`:

```
sudo chvt 1
```

should take you to `tty1`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the answer was <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.